# "maybe as long as a year or more:

Tags: meaning

*It’s no small wonder that Mary was so inquisitive of the angel; she was still a virgin and would know no man sexually for several months, **maybe as long as a year or more**  (Matthew 1:18; Luke 1:34)*.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Joseph-and-Mary.html

I have a question regarding the phrase "as long as" used in the above passage. The Dictionary says that this phrase is used when we talk about "something continuing for the amount of time that you want, need, or is possible". Do you think that this (the meaning) is the case in my example too?

Comment: It refers to a period of time lasting at least several months, possibly more than a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As long as*, *as short as*, *as many as*, and the like can be used in front of a number to emphasize how big or small the number is.

Here's what *Practical English Usage* says about this construction:

> ## (379.3)
>
> Before a number, *as long as* can be used to suggest great length.
>
> > *These meetings can last **as long as** four hours.*
>
> ## (203.6)
>
> *As much/many as* can be used before a number to mean 'the large amount/quantity of.
>
> > *Some of these fish can weigh **as much as 80**kg.*
> >     *There are sometimes **as many as 40** students in the classes.*
>
> *As little/few* can be used to mean 'the small amount/quantity of'.
>
> > *You can fly to Paris for **as little as 20** euros.*

Examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

> Our mission could've been **as short as** two and a half months, but it was extended to almost six months.
>
> You may have to wait for **as long as** six months, and availability is severely limited.
>
> Every year, **as many as** 60,000 come to the Mackinac Bridge for the Annual Bridge Walk.

*As close as*, *as near as*, *as far as*, and *as far away as* can be used before countries, cities, towns, etc. to emphasize the distance between the current location and the one being referred to.

> Nuts on Clark imports products from **as far as** Australia and Brazil.
>
> We received more than 2,000 entries from **as near as** Newark and **as far away as** Japan and Africa.
>
> Dads came from **as close as** Pittsburgh and **as far away as** Wisconsin and Tennessee.